# Difference between patch and update

Tags: installation, upgrade, updates, patch

On creating Installers, I came across both patch and upgrade. Whats is the major difference between a patch and and upgrade? Is a patch similar to update?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about definitions of words.

Comment: I think this question shouldn't have been closed. After all, it is an interesting question. How can I open this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A patch is basically a diff between two MSI databases of the same product (e.g. v1.0.0 and v1.0.1) and can be installed only on target machines where its target MSI (i.e. v1.0.0) is installed. It can be used only for updating an installed product. It cannot be installed standalone.

A major upgrade is the installation of a new product version (e.g. v2.0.0) over an old version (e.g. v1.0.0). When performed, a major upgrade firstly removes completely the old version and, then install the new version of your product. An installation package built as a major upgrade can also be installed as a standalone installation.

Check the [Patch Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370596(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Major Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369786(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows Installer articles for more details.

Comment: Hello Herman, 
In Windows installer, how can I do "update certain dlls" only but not a completely new versions ? Something more advanced than a patch that can upgrade whichever target (for example a patch103 that will bring any version of v100, v101, v102 to v103 ) because I have 2-3 dlls and files that need to be upgraded; but more light-weight than a full upgrades/installer ?

Answer (score 4):

All patches are update, but not all updates are patches.

> A patch is a piece of software designed to update a computer program
>   or its supporting data, to fix or improve it. This includes fixing
>   security vulnerabilities and other bugs, and improving the usability
>   or performance. **Though meant to fix problems**, poorly designed
>   patches can sometimes introduce new problems (see software
>   regressions). (source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(computing)))

A new feature in the system is not a patch, but it is also an update.