# How do patches and update be applied to different old version?

Tags: updates, patch

For example, if version 1 of a software is distributed to 2 client A and B. When version 2 comes out A take the update, but B didn't. Now when version 3 comes out both A and B wants to update.

So how do the update program works? Does it need to patch all the intermediate version before give B the latest version?

Comment: Just to clarify, you reference an "update," but then you mention "the latest version." Do you mean update or upgrade?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand some term. What I mean is to give the software new feature so that should be upgrade.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your question is not specific enough anyone to provide a good answer. In its current form, your question is likely to result in answer based on opinion rather than fact. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's talk about the differences between a few terms first.

**Updates vs. Upgrades:**
You mention "the latest version," of the software, so I am guessing you mean the latest major release of the software right (i.e. version 1 to version 2)? In that case, you want to refer to an "upgrade" not an "update." 
 Check out this explanation on the English Stack Exchange: [Difference between an Upgrade and an Update](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13353/are-there-any-differences-between-update-and-upgrade)

In short, the way I have always understood it:
Updates - these apply to the *current* version of the software (just like patches)

Upgrade - this is basically a new and improved piece of software (a new version)

Note based on your comment above: 
 An update can provide new features as well (but they apply to the *current* version of the software). Those same features may also be included in new versions of the software but just as features (not updates).

**Patches vs. Updates:** 
Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998393/difference-between-patch-and-update). Someone says "all patches are updates, but not all updates are patches". You can have an update to a version of software that is not necessarily fixing a problem (what a patch would do). It may be adding a new feature. However, a patch is considered a type of update.

**Back to the Question: To Upgrade or To Patch and Upgrade?**
According to Wikipedia:

> A patch is a piece of software designed to update a computer program
>   or its supporting data, to fix or improve it.

A patch is generally used to fix the *current* version of the software. This may be oversimplifying it a bit, but if you upgrade, it's like you're getting an all new piece of software. So, even if both A and B have different versions, if there is a new version out, there is no need to patch and then get the new version. When you get a new version, it's like your starting fresh. You no longer remember the old patched up version of the old software.

Also, just from personal experience, let's say A and B both work at a particular company, that company may require both of them to upgrade to the newest version when it is available.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help. So do the software company need to maintain patch to all the supported version of their software so far? (each version has a different patch). BTW, I'm talking about the case where some generic software (like Firefox,...) and some of the clients didn't update regularly when a new one comes out

Comment: No problem. I think that depends on the company. In my experience, companies usually upgrade everyone to the same version so when they send out updates, they're sending out updates for one version (rather than several). If the company allows employees to use several versions, they might send out updates for each version. They might also leave it up to the employees to maintain updates (which can be a bad idea). By the way, if that answered your question, can you mark it as the answer? It helps so if other people have the same question, they see it has a valid answer.

Comment: Just to be sure. So the only way to deal with different version is to give users the latest installer and install it like a fresh new program, is there another way to minimize the size of the upgrade (e.g. using diff)?

Comment: There are lot of different ways companies can handle patches and updates in terms of how they package them. They don't have to release a new version, but your question was do they have to get all the previous patches befo re getting a new version. And they don't. A company doesn't have to push upgrade. They can allow employees to upgrade if they want and when they want. It all depends on the company, it's rules and the software.